# Downloading a txt file shows System.Byte[] and how to convert it to a string? c#

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, visual-studio, ascx

I currently have a form that allows to me to successfully upload a txt file into a SQL database. Now I'm trying to download that text file (or any txt file) but I'm not sure how to properly convert bytes. It will display the column name "Solution File" and when it shows the row its "System.Byte"
I tried using byte[] or BitConverter but I am unsure how.

[This is the result.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uWjSc.png)

This is my code:

```
//this is the code for "Download"
protected void DownloadButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string ConnectionStrings = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionStrings"].ConnectionString;
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConnectionStrings))
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT SolutionFile FROM dbo.acca_Problems where ProblemID = " + Request.QueryString["id"]);
        {
            
            using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
            {
                cmd.Connection = con;
                sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
              using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
                {           
                    sda.Fill(dt);
                    
                    //Build the Text file data.
                    string txt = string.Empty;

                    
                    foreach (DataColumn column in dt.Columns)
                    {
                         txt += column.ColumnName + "\r\n";
                        
                    }

                    //Add new line.
                    txt += "\r\n";

                    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
                    {
                        foreach (DataColumn column in dt.Columns)
                        {
                            
                            //Add the Data rows.
                            txt += row[column.ColumnName].ToString() + "\r\n";

                            
                        }

                        //Add new line.
                        txt += "\r\n";
                        //}

                        //Download the Text file.
                        Response.Clear();
                        Response.Buffer = true;
                        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=ProblemExport.txt");
                        Response.Charset = "";
                        Response.ContentType = "application/text";
                        Response.Output.Write(txt);
                        Response.Flush();
                        Response.End();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

 }
```

Comment: You could replace the majority of this code with probably five lines of code using [Dapper](https://github.com/DapperLib/Dapper), it would already be in `string` format, and it wouldn't suffer from SQL injection vulnerabilities like this code does.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I don't doubt that but I'm just trying to understand byte conversions even though this isn't probably the most optimal way.

Comment: I can't see how the code given will generate that file; I can see the part that adds the column name and the new line, but there then seems to  be nothing in between adding that newline and sending it down the wire, that would add a byte array to a string eg `txt += row["MyByteArrayColumn"]` (causing the byte array's ToString to be invoked, rendering the type of the object into the file). Also, why do you have a response flush/end on every pass of the inner loop? This is highly illogical and could only work for a one row, one column table

Answer (score 1):

here is an example of converting to and from a byte array (assuming UTF-8 enconding).

```cs
string toConvert = "Test string";

// From string to byte array
byte[] buffer = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(toConvert);

// From byte array to string
string s = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
```